# NOt able to update existing data of a application form

Tags: php

I am editing my application form.So what i am Doing telling you here..I am already logged in

- First of all i am giving a edit link(edit_profile1.php) on my home page
- NOw i am asking again for username and password so that unauthorized user can not making editing in your profile
- NOw on edit_profile1.php i am checking username and password sent by user to the username and password stored in database
- If username and password are correct then i am redirected to edit_profile2.php
- Here I  am creating a form with same text boxes as i used in filling the application form(i am using same name for boxes).Here is a button with name update

For the last page edit_profile3.php i am giving coading here

```
<?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$con)
        {
        die('Could Not Connect:'.mysql_error());
        } 
        mysql_select_db("tcs",$con);

$usr=$_POST["username"];                 
$pwd=hash('sha1',$_POST['password']);   

$query="select * from employee where Username='$usr' and Password='$pwd'";   

$result=mysql_query($query,$con);


if ($result) 
{

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sql="update employee set ($row['Username']=$usr,$row['Password']=$pwd");

$deepak=mysql_query($sql,$con);

if($deepak)
{
    echo "Updation Successfull"
}
```

}
  ?>

Now when i excute this error is coming like this
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in F:\Study Material\Linux\xampp\htdocs\edit_profile3.php on line 21

```
Line number 21 is 
 $sql="update employee set ($row['Username']=$usr,$row['Password']=$pwd");
```

NOw i am not getting where i am getting wrong.Plz also tell me is there any other method for updating application forms any another logic.Plz check out above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem with the parentheses that others have already pointed out, shouldn't it be like this?

```
"update employee set password=$pwd WHERE username=$usr"
```

If you also want to change the username, do something like this:

```
"update employee set username=$new_username, password=$pwd WHERE username=$old_username"
```

See the [UPDATE documentation for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for a description of the syntax.

Also, putting strings like this directly into SQL queries is risky - if you're not careful you could leave an SQL injection invulnerability. You should use query parameters to ensure that your code is secure. Read more about it from [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: ok fine i remove the quote problem but still the same error..and plz cheak out properly i want to do edit evrything not only password but also username thats why i give command

$sql="update employee set ($row['Username']=$usr,$row['Password']=$pwd)"

BUt this is not working

Comment: @Deepak: Sorry, but you're doing it wrong. Have you ever used UPDATE in SQL before? I suggest you read the documentation (see link in my updated answer) and some tutorials and try playing around with UPDATE in the query browser until you understand it.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion sir ,In future i will follow it sure.But now its urgent sir thats why i am so insisting here..

About problem
May be  i am not able to tell you properly what i wnat.Ok plz listen once again..First of all i am fetching all form data from dataabse into a form .My form have onely two field username and password.Now i want to change both username and password...
That's why i am writing $row['Username'](old value)=$usr(new value) and $row['Password'](old value)=$pwd(new value)..plz tell me correct code once so that i can grab it and can implement into my project.plz

Answer (score 0):

Your closing bracket `)` is outside the query string.

Use a PHP editor with syntax highlighting, they help see such problems straight away.

And [**the PHP manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) is very good, and always good to have handy.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not properly written:

```
$sql="update employee set ($row['Username']=$usr,$row['Password']=$pwd)";
```

The quote must be after the ' ) '.